# How to remove object from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have class with ArrayList of teams and i want remove team which name is "FREE";

so i tried:

```
 public void removeFree()
{

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTeams ; i++ )
    {
        if (this.getListOfTeams().get(i).getName() == "FREE")
        {
            this.getListOfTeams().remove(i);
        }
        else
        {}
    }
}
```

That makes my app crash.

Answer (score 3):

Use, equals() method to check if two strings are meaningfully equal. `==` operator just checks if two reference variables refer to the same object.

```
    if (this.getListOfTeams().get(i).getName() == "FREE")
```

should be

```
    if (this.getListOfTeams().get(i).getName().equals("FREE"))
```

Also to add more, even if you use equals() you'd get `ConcurrentModificationException` as you are removing the elements from the arrayList while iterating over it. you have to use an iterator and remove elements from it rather.

```
Iterator<Team> itr = getListOfTeams.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
  if (itr.next().getName().equals("FREE"))
        {
            itr.remove();
        }
        else
        {}
}
}
```

Comment: It could also help avoiding NPE's to invoke `equals()` on the literal String `"FREE"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To remove an element from a `List` while iterating it, it's safer to use an `Iterator` along with the `remove` method:

```
for (Iterator it = getListOfTeams().iterator;it.hasNext();) {
    String name = it.next();
    if ("FREE".equals(name) {
        it.remove();
    }
    else{}
}
```

Please note how String value comparison in Java should usually be done by means of the `String.equals()` method. `==` is the reference equality operator. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/851811)

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your `for` loop. Shouldn't `it.hasNext()` be the condition, not the update?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove an item while you are looping the same ArrayList. You need to clone first, iterate the cloned list and then delete the items of the first pointer.

so consider this:

```
List<Object> arrayToIterate = getListOfTeams().clone();
for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTeams ; i++ )
{
    if (tarrayToIterate.get(i).getName().equals("FREE"))
    {
        this.getListOfTeams().remove(i);
    }
    else
    {}
}
```

Also you are comparing an string with == instead of equals.